# A proof of the ratio test for convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum c_n$  be  a  series of  positive  numbers. Assume  that  $$\lim_n {{c_{n+1}}\over {c_n}} = r$$

If $0\lt r\lt 1$ then the series converges ; if $r\gt 1$ then diverges .

If $r\lt 1$ ; choose  an $s$ such that $r\lt s\lt 1$ . Then  $\exists N\in \mathbb N $ s.t. for all $n\ge N$ $$c_{n+1}\le sc_n$$

How  did  they  get  this  $?$

Comment: Can you prove this similar claim: Suppose $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n} = r$. Then, for every $s>r$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n\ge N$, we have $a_{n}\le s$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $${{c_{n+1}}\over c_n}=s_n$$   Then, the given condition is $$\lim_n s_n =r$$ So, for  any given  $\epsilon \gt 0$ , there  exist $N\in \mathbb N$ s.t. 
$$s_n\in (r-\epsilon ,r+\epsilon)\ 
 for\ \ n\ge N\\ or,|s_n-r|\lt \epsilon \\or,|s_n|\lt |r|+\epsilon\\ i.e. s_n\lt r+\epsilon$$
(Remember $\{s_n\}$s are *positive*.) So if we  take $\epsilon =s-r$, we are done .

Answer (score 3):

If a sequence $u_n$ has limit $c$ then for any $\varepsilon>0$ "eventually" all the terms are within $\varepsilon$ of $c,$ where eventually means there is $N$ so that the terms are within $\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N.$ This can be adapted here to the sequence $c_{n+1}/c_n$ which by hypothesis approaches $r$ with $0<r<1.$ Then multiply through by the positive $c_n.$

The suggestion of choosing $s$ with $r<s<1$ is for the rest of the proof, and so you can let $\varepsilon=(s-r)/2$ in the above description.